# bash shell script which adds output of commands

Tags: bash, unix, script, shell-script

Let's say I have a command called `foo` which prints a number to the screen when called:

```
$ foo
3
```

Let's also say I have another command called `bar` which prints another number to the screen when called:

```
$ bar
5
```

I'm looking to write a shell script which will arithmetically add together the output of `foo` and `bar` (3+5=8). How would I do that? (The outputs from the commands are not known ahead of time. They just so happen to have been 3 and 5 the last time they were run. They could have been something else.)

Comment: What do you mean by adding together? Are the program outputs always integers and you want 3+5=8 or are they strings and you want '3'+'5'='35'.

Comment: they're integers, and I'm looking to add them (3+5=8), not concatenate them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use bash's `let` to evalutate arithmetric expressions.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`echo 3`
b=`echo 5`

let c=$a+$b
echo $c
```

Just substitute the calls to `echo` with your program calls.

Comment: You can omit the dollar signs in a `let` statement.

Comment: @Dennis: I know, but this way it does at least *seem* consistent. The shortest way (sadly?) is often the most likely to confuse (cf. Perl ;)

Comment: `let` is the devil.  It feels like BASIC, and makes baby pandas cry.  The double-paren mechanism doesn't harm pandas. ;)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `let` is to use double-parenthesis syntax:

```
(( c = $(foo) + $(bar) ))
```

or

```
echo $(( $(foo) + $(bar) ))
```

or using variables, you can omit the dollar sign on the right hand side of the equals:

```
(( c += $(foo) + num ))
```

(which also illustrates an incremental assignment)

If you're using non-integers you can use `bc`:

```
echo "$(foo) + $(bar)" | bc
```

or

```
c=$(echo "$(foo) + $(bar)" | bc)
```

One advantage of using double parentheses is that you can put spaces around the operands and operators to make things more readable:

```
(( c = ( a + b ) * ( i - j ) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```
bc < <({ foo ; echo + ; bar ; } | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo)
```

If the output is integers only:

```
$(( $(foo) + $(bar) ))
```